# Постинг картинки с текстом и ссылой в телеграмм/telegram

Tags: json, post, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь запостить фото с описанием и кнопкой-ссылкой в бота телеграм, чтобы он запостил это в канал.
Все работает отлично, фотка постится с описанием, но я хочу, чтобы внизу была кнопка "перейти". И вот с ней у меня проблема.
Все делаю post-запросом

```
https://api.telegram.org/botТУТ_ПРИВАТНЫЙ_КЛЮЧ/sendPhoto?chat_id=@ТУТ_НИК_КАНАЛА&photo=URL_ФОТО&caption=ТУТ_CAPTION&reply_markup=InlineKeyboardButtom(text="test", url="ya.ru")
```

А в ответе приходит вот это: `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во-первых**, кнопка - это объект. Как Вы пытаетесь передать объект в http-запросе? `reply_markup=InlineKeyboardButtom(text="test", url="ya.ru")` невалидный JSON, как Вам и говорят в тексте ошибки, более того - это вообще не JSON. Таким образом, приведите объект к JSON-виду для начала. Можно воспользоваться [этим сервисом](http://jsoneditoronline.org/).
**Во-вторых**, этот объект затем нужно будет преобразовать (не только этот объект, но и вообще весь запрос в целом) в приемлемую для http кодировку, для этого можно воспользоваться [этим сервисом](http://www.url-encode-decode.com).

---

**Пример** валидного запроса для отправки текстового сообщения со встроенной кнопкой:

```
https://api.telegram.org/<YOUR_BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=12345&text=TEST&reply_markup=%7B%0D%0A++%22inline_keyboard%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A++++%5B%0D%0A++++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++%22text%22%3A+%22test%22%2C%0D%0A++++++++%22url%22%3A+%22ya.ru%22%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%5D%0D%0A++%5D%0D%0A%7D
```

Валидный JSON для использованной в примере кнопки:

```
{
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [
      {
        "text": "test",
        "url": "ya.ru"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, мужик!!